# Installing scikit-learn and use PyPy as Python Interpreter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conda, pypy, mamba

I'm trying to create a conda env (actually I'm using Mamba) whith PyPy as default interpreter and then installing Scikit-Learn to perform machine-learning tasks.
I succeded in the environment creation and setup with:

`mamba create -n sklearn -c conda-forge pypy python`

In fact, running `python` inside the shell after env activation returns:

```
Python 3.9.16 | packaged by conda-forge | (feeb267e, Jan 18 2023, 16:13:01)
[PyPy 7.3.11 with GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>>
```

Then i tried to install scikit-learn package with `mamba install -n sklearn -c conda-forge scikit-learn` and i get this output:

```
Looking for: ['scikit-learn']

conda-forge/linux-64                                          No change
conda-forge/noarch                                  11.1MB @   2.3MB/s  5.0s
Could not solve for environment specs
Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides python 3.6.9 1_73_pypy needed by pypy-7.3.1-h9f0ad1d_1

The environment can't be solved, aborting the operation
```

I tried both with conda and pip install, but I got other errors about package conflicts. I also tried to make an environment with `mamba create -n myenv -c conda-forge scikit-learn`, but this will install the standard CPython implementation as the interpreter.

There are ways to achieve this or should I get rid of PyPy?

Comment: I believe you need to use a C compatibility layer to run some libraires on PyPy (such as Numpy, scikit,...)

[hpy][1]


  [1]: https://hpyproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

The conda-forge recipe for scikit-learn has not yet been updated for pypy3.9. You could try to build from source.

Comment: I found out that numpy isn't supported by pypy, so I think that building from source could lead to other problems. I will try if I'll have time, thanks.

Comment: Numpy __is__ supported, `conda install numpy scipy` should work.